# React caching rendered components

Tags: javascript, caching, reactjs

Is there any open source code or examples that try to do caching of rendered React components on memcached or something simillar?
Anyone that has already dealt with this?

Comment: You probably want to just save the rendered html; the same way you'd cache any templating language output.

Answer (score 1):

Like FakeRainBrigand suggested, you can just save the html. However, one neat thing about react is that every component is represented with state/props. This means if you suitably represent your UI with those fields, you should be able to reproduce your page given the same state/props.

This could possibly mean that if you stored the state/props somehow, and loaded it back up, you could effectively "cache" the components for later, and very cheaply at that. I'm thinking something similar to this below:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    if(this.props.id) {
        provider.load(this.props.id, function (result) {
            this.setState(result);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So what you're suggesting is caching only the state and re-render?

Comment: It will work in most cases. Obviously there will be some breakdown if there are changes to the underlying data (you have element x expanded, but the data for element x is no longer valid), so you will have to figure out how to merge those conflicts. Overall it should be a good way to do it. I've never written anything like it before, so if you end up doing it I would love to hear how it worked out for you!

Comment: But what if just react rendering is very slow and you can not use shouldComponentUpdate in a particular case.  Lets say i have a sorting problem, where I have 1000 entires to sort, sorting them on the client side and putting  the sorted elements into a component as a prop is fast, but each component has 2 other components, so rendering can get a bit slowish.