# How to save or cache a Component's html?

Tags: reactjs

I know you can store a Component state and alter it so that the element is "re rendered", however in my use case, there is a situation I have where the rendering is just not up to speed.

What im looking for is that once a Component has been rendered, I want its html code, including the html of its children.

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
render() {
  return(
          <ChildComponent/>
        );
}

componentDidMount() {
  // Get the html code of this Component here
  // Something like:
  // <div>
  //    <span>Child component</span>
  // </div>
}
```

I've looked at this similar question:
[React caching rendered components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959357/react-caching-rendered-components)

But it doesn't go in depth on how one may obtain the html elements as a string

Comment: Is server side rendering an option?  If so, take a look at this:  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html

Comment: unfortunately im not using SSR. Is there perhaps a way to clone elements?

Comment: Can you explain your situation in more detail?  Does `<ChildComponent>` use `state` and/or `props`?

Comment: Yes, child component does have state and props

Comment: Then is cloning the `<ChildComponent />`'s HTML really going to help? What does the child component render?  Why is it slow? Is there a way to achieve the same functionality as a stateless functional component? Maybe you could tell React to avoid doing a deep comparison and instead tell React when to rerender the component using `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: I'm using react-dnd to render an element where the user is dragging their mouse. The thing is, my element is somewhat complicated, and so rendering it instantly, on drag, is a bit slow. I just thought that I could bypass the rendering by just caching it at the start. Sort of like caching data on the RAM instead of loading it up from the Storage every time.

Comment: Check this https://thoughtspile.github.io/2019/01/06/vdom-bend-memo/

Answer (score 0):

You either want to figure out a way to [`renderToString`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) [on the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666241/does-react-dom-server-work-on-the-client-side) or access the DOM directly, which returns the actual (not pretty) DOM node.

Here's an example using [`findDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) and [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).outerHTML
    );
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div id="demo">
        Ranch it up!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='View'></div>
```

I imagine this being not all that useful if you want to actually use this string somewhere (render it), so it's probably better to save store all the data (`state`) and go from there.

Comment: I appreciate your effort in this. Saving the data in state is what I would normally do, but having the need to render things really fast just forced me to look elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this same issue while working on our datagrid product http://www.reactdatagrid.com - We basically store the HTML tag as well as the attribute values in an object. Our render method looks something like this (not actual code):

```
render(){
    this.reactElement = React.createElement(tagName, propertyBag, children);
    return this.reactElement;
}
```

We have a fairly complex grid product and this works reasonably fast for us.